# API which is working from postman and also working from browser but same is not working in Nodejs getting error ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, axios, econnreset

**Postman API :**
[image]

**API call through browser**
[image]

> Nodejs Code:

```
  var axios = require('axios');

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v2.0/admin/tenant/config/active',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

- "dependencies": {
  "@azure/identity": "^1.0.3",
  "@azure/keyvault-secrets": "^4.0.4",
  "@microsoft/recognizers-text-data-types-timex-expression": "1.1.4",
  "@types/node": "^14.0.24",
  "activedirectory": "^0.7.2",
  "agentkeepalive": "^4.2.1",
  "async-hooks-map": "^1.2.0",
  "axios": "^0.19.2",
  "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
  "botbuilder": "~4.9.0",
  "botbuilder-ai": "~4.9.0",
  "botbuilder-dialogs": "~4.9.0",
  "botbuilder-testing": "^4.10.0",
  "botframework-schema": "^4.10.0",
  "cors": "^2.8.4",
  "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
  "express": "^4.17.3",
  "express-session": "^1.16.1",
  "express-validator": "5.2.0",
  "log4js": "^4.5.1",
  "mongodb": "^3.6.0",
  "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
  "replace": "~1.2.0",
  "simple-ssh": "^1.0.0",
  "typed-rest-client": "1.0.7",
  "util": "^0.12.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "@types/restify": "8.4.2",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
  "tslint": "~6.1.2",
  "typescript": "~3.9.2"
  }
  }

Error:

> Error: read ECONNRESET
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
> errno: -4077,
> code: 'ECONNRESET',
> syscall: 'read',
> config: {
> url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v2.0/admin/tenant/config/active',
> method: 'get',
> headers: {
> Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
> 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
> 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2'
> },
> transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
> transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
> timeout: 0,
> adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
> xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
> xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
> maxContentLength: -1,
> validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
> data: undefined
> },

Can anyone please tell me what can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.

You should be able to surf to that URL with a web browser, because it's just a GET. That can help you to double-check it.

One thing that is rather strange, is the double slash in your path: `//`. Postman is pretty intelligent, and perhaps postman just simplifies the request before sending it out.

Anyway, I tested your code on one of my own webservers, and it works fine (for a different URL though).

Having said that, the ECONNRESET does indicate that there was a connection, but it was closed by the server unexepectedly. Why it was closed, is entirely up to the behavior of your webserver.